# How to make a drop down menu in jQuery reset when in different screen size?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, footer

I have a four columns footer on desktop version that turns into a dropdown menu on the mobile version. When I click & open one of the dropdown menus & then I resize the screen to desktop & go back to mobile version it will stay open. I am trying to find a way that when I resize the screen to desktop & forth it will go back to be closed.

Here is my dropdown in mobile version closed:

[image]

Here is my dropdown in mobile version opened:

[image]

In Desktop my dropdown disappears & becomes a four column grid with Bootstrap 4.

My jquery code for the dropdown menu:

```
// Var Declaration
    var footerMobileMenu = $('.footer__menu--mobile');
    // Footer dropdown menu
    footerMobileMenu.on('click', function(){
        footerMobileMenu.not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
        // Rotate SVG
        footerMobileMenu.not(this).find('h3').removeClass('rotated-svg');
        $(this).find('h3').toggleClass('rotated-svg');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(window).on('resize')`

```
$(window).on('resize' , function(){
  if($(window).width() > 500){ // change 500 with the width you want
     // code here
     $('.footer__menu--mobile ul').slideDown(); // use this to show th ul's
     $('h3.rotated-svg').removeClass('rotated-svg'); // remove h3 class
  } 
});
```

<sup>**Additional Note:** if you want the click event to work just on mobile devices make and `if($(window).width() > 500){` inside the click event</sup>

**Update#1** <sup>*I was trying to avoid using the resize method if possible*</sup>

In this case you'll need to use `@media` in css with `!important`

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
  .footer__menu--mobile ul{
     display : block !important;
  }
  h3.rotated-svg{
    /* reset the rotation here */
  }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** With `@media` and while you want to reset the things I recommend to use `addClass()` and `toggleClass()` also with the `ul`s instead of `slideUp()` and `slideToggle()` and use `max-height:0` and `max-height:1000px` on the appended class</sup>